# Replacing stove solid-state-relay

Tags: electrical, stove, relay

I am replacing a relay for an appliance (stove)

I cannot find a replacement relay, however I thought I'd confirm if the following relays would be compatible:

The original relay is:

input 90-250 VAC output 40-440 VAC 40 Amps

The only replacement option I have found so far is the following:

1. input 90-250 VAC output 24-440VAC 40 Amps

Does that 24 and 40 voltage make a big difference would there be a possible issue with my stove if I were to make this change?

Thanks

Comment: There are other considerations besides simple voltage and current. Size? Mounting? How much current is needed to activate the relay? Temperature constraints? If you list the stove model # and the existing relay model # (if you have that), it should be possible to find a more direct replacement.

Comment: The range 24-440 includes the range 40-440, so electrically that's probably fine. And solid state relays generally require very little current to activate.

I am assuming you have already checked that the physical footprint (size and pin locations) is the same as the one you want to replace.

@manassehkatz does raise a good point about temperature constraints. Stoves get hot, strangely enough...

And I agree that if you want to be sure, you really need to give us the part number of the old relay so we can do a proper replacement evaluation against _all_ the specs.

Comment: (This is an example of why I post comments -- and then get grumped at in Meta because they think anything that resembles an answer, even if it's a bad or incomplete answer, should be an Answer. Can't win. Can't break even. Could leave the game...)

Comment: You should acquire the replacement part through the manufacturer or other legitimate local HVAC supply or quality electrical contract supply (Mouser, GALCO).  What you should definitely not do is mail-order from general-product sites such as eBay, Amazon Marketplace, AliExpress, Banggood, Wish.com, DealExtreme, Newegg, or Walmart or Sears' online site (which blend in Amazon and eBay results). That is flooded with cheap Chinese which is not safe and not certified.

Comment: I'm currently working with a Thor Kitchen Stove HRD3606. I have contacted Thor Kitchen and they do have a few relays that can send. The current relays do sit on heat sinks, and are mounted at the back of the stove. 

The current spec of the relays from what I can tell it is:
LRS1-1-340AA
40A AC-12
Load: 40-440VAC
Output: 90-250VAC. Everything I have read online about Thor Kitchen stoves is that the relays go very often. Just trying to see if I use something better than what Thor provides